# Cheerio.js not grabbing non inline styles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I'm currently using node.js to scrape a word document saved as an .htm, then rewrite it for a shell.

I have create < li > tags but the way these word documents are saved out I have to hunt for them by looking for margin-left. like this:

```
$("p","td:nth-child(2)").each(function(){
   var marginLeft = this.css("margin-left");
}
```

I have it working pretty great so far.   The only trouble I am facing is when the style is actually applied via a class.

Here is the conflicting class:

```
p.RNBullet1, li.RNBullet1, div.RNBullet1{
   mso-style-name:"*RN Bullet1";
   mso-style-unhide:no;
   mso-style-link:"*RN Bullet1 Char";
   margin-top:0in;
   margin-right:0in;
   margin-bottom:0in;
   margin-left:.2in;
   text-indent:-.2in;
   mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
   mso-list:l12 level1 lfo5;
   font-size:11.0pt;
   font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
   mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
}
```

It will return that with an undefined, when clearly it has a value.

Any insight into this would be helpful I've going crazy over here.

Comment: Try Phantom.JS. `cheerio` is just a DOM traversal tool, it doesn't compute styles.

Comment: @vkurchatkin the op is probably trying to use cheerio inside node js. As far as I know phantom js can not be used inside node js.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma yeah, he'll probably need something like https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node. I wish PhantomJS was just a node module...

Comment: Well if cheerio is just a DOM traversing tool.  Then I guess there are a few ways I could handle it.   I could use Juice to take css styles and apply them as inline, prior to cheerior.    Or this PhantomJS business.  I'll have to report back which route I went.   Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As vkurchatkin pointed out above, cheerio just traverses the DOM.   It doesn't read style sheets

This was the answer:  https://npmjs.org/package/juice

Basically I loaded cheerio with what juice returned.

Juice will turn styes into inline.